# What wrong with delay property in react-loadable?

Tags: reactjs, react-loadable

I'm using react-loadable library for lazy-loading in reactJS. It works very well for rendering component. But when i use the delay property, the render time is not effected. So, What i need to update here ?

```
const Home = Loadable({
  loader: () => import('./Home'),
  loading: Loading,
  delay: 5000
});

const Test = Loadable({
  loader: () => import('./Test'),
  loading: Loading,
  delay: 5000
});

return (
  <Router>
    <div className="App">
      <Link to="/"> Home </Link>
      <Link to="/test"> Test </Link>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route path='/test' component={Test} />
    </div>
  </Router>
);
```

Thanks for any helping.

Comment: Where is your `Loading` function defined? I don't see it.

Comment: @mattdevio I defined it in this file, too. i miss to show it.

It here : 
function Loading({ pastDelay }) {
  console.log(pastDelay);
  return pastDelay ? <h3>Loading...</h3> : null;
}

Answer (score 3):

Delay doesn't affect the rendering time of the actual component but it delays the rendering time of Loading component.

Here is excerpt from official Documentation:

> **Avoiding Flash Of Loading Component**
>
> Sometimes components load really quickly (<200ms) and the loading screen only quickly flashes on the screen.
> A number of user studies have proven that this causes users to perceive things taking longer than they really have. If you don't show anything, users perceive it as being faster.
> So your loading component will also get a pastDelay prop which will only be true once the component has taken longer to load than a set delay.

Source: https://github.com/jamiebuilds/react-loadable#avoiding-flash-of-loading-component

Comment: First of all, I wanna say thanks for your answer. This topic should be closed. I've resolved this problem.